# Python make list of dicts unique by a value

Tags: python

Given list of dicts:

`[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Sam'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bob'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Mark'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Jane'}]`

Need to turn it into:

`[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Sam'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Jane'}]`

Just take any "record" unique by id. How can i do it in single line ?

Comment: There are probably many duplicates for this question that haven't been tracked down... there's another roundup hunt for me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby`, it is assumed that dictionaries with the same id are arranged consecutively:

```
>>> lst
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Sam'},
 {'id': 1, 'name': 'Bob'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'Mark'},
 {'id': 2, 'name': 'Jane'}]
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> [next(mappings) for _, mappings in groupby(lst, key=itemgetter('id'))]
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Sam'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Mark'}]
```

Or dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> list({mp['id']: mp for mp in lst}.values())
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'Bob'}, {'id': 2, 'name': 'Jane'}]
```